# each of us might get fired

Tags: modal-verbs, ambiguity, quantifiers

a. Each of us might get fired tomorrow.

b. We might each get fired tomorrow.

================

c. All of us might get fired tomorrow.

d. We might all get fired tomorrow.

===================

e. Every one of us might get fired tomorrow.

==================

Which of the above sentences mean:

1. It is possible that we will all be fired together

and which of them mean:

2. It is possible for any one of us to get fired

Maybe some of the are ambiguous?

Many thanks.

Comment: We might all get fired. Both of us might get fired.

Answer (score 1):

I would read a and b to mean "any one of us might get fired" )with a being my preference of those two options) while d would be "We are facing being fired as a group". e just sounds awkward.

Answer (score 1):

a) each might  "possibly none to all"
b) might each  "none to all"
c) might all  "possibly all as a group"
d) every one  "anyone or all"

A better "singular" choice might be "anyone could" but is less certain than "some or many will"